# ¿Cómo funciona un port?

Tags: aplicación-web

Por ejemplo, puedo empezar una aplicación en port localhost:8080 y si voy al browser puedo ver mi aplicación. Entiendo que es como una endpoint de comunicación pero no más.

¿Alguien me puede explicar en forma sencilla cómo funciona un port?

Por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa cuándo abro Chrome, se usa ports?

Comment: Y has investigado algo al respecto?

Comment: Sí, pero no he encontrado una buena explicación sobre el tema. Bueno, para mí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender de manera simple lo que es un puerto de red, puedes usar una analogia simple, por ejemplo, una computadora tiene varios puertos fisicos (USB, VGA, HDMI, PS-2) y cada cual se encarga de una funcion especifica, en redes los puertos funcionan de manera similar de cierto sentido, cada cual tiene una funcion especifica, independientemente de que puedas configurarlos para usarlos con el protocolo que desees, te dejo un enlace con los puertos mas usados en los protocolos TCP y UDP (aunque existen mas protocolos) para que te hagas una mejor idea, este es un ejemplo sensillo, tendras que investigar mucho mas para conocer mas a fondo.

[Puertos TCP y UDP mas usados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Puertos_de_red)

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha ayudado

Comment: Si te ha ayudado puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada? Gracias!